# How to access server query string with $_GET from earlier in page?

Tags: php

Ok, I have a link that I want to be accessed by another part of the same file, but it would take `$_GET` to send the user to the correct part. I feel like I'm trying to go around in circles - I understand that it's not "GETting" the variable because it hasn't reached the page yet, but I can't reach the page until I grab the variable... I just don't understand what I need to do in order for me to be able to go to the page where `$deck=$_GET['deck'];`. I hope that all made sense and any help is greatly appreciated!!

```
$qs=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

if ( $qs == "id=".$row['id']."&where=collect") {

    echo "<h1>Profile > <a href=\"profile.php?id=".$id."\">".$name."</a> > Collecting</h1><center>";

    $select=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cards` ORDER BY `filename` ASC");
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        $filename=$row2['filename'];
        $deckname=$row2['deckname'];
        $cardcount=$row2['count'];
        $count=substr_count($collecting, $filename);
        $num=rand(1, $cardcount);
        $n=sprintf('%02d', $num);

        if($count!=0) {
            echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$id."&where=collect&deck=".$filename."\"><img src=\"".$cardurl.$filename.$n.".png\"></a>";
        }
    }
    echo "</center>";
}

$deck=$_GET['deck'];
if ( $qs == "id=".$row['id']."&where=collect&deck=".$deck) {    
    echo "This is the ".$deck." page";
}
```

Comment: maybe im going blind, sorry, but where is the varable `$collecting` being set?

Comment: Sorry, that was set much earlier in the page. All of the variables (not including `$deck`) work perfect - the issue is only getting access to the final query string.

Comment: Honestly, I can click on the link and it will take me to the page, but before I click on it I get `Notice: Undefined index: deck in...`

Comment: I guess for now I am going to just send them to a new file with all the same info, but I would still like to know how to get around this using the same file.

Comment: It's a bit hard to visualize what you are trying to achieve here. You only have 1 file and you want it's content to change depending on certain GET variable values (one has a link, another doesn't have a link)? Also, you are probably getting undefined index warnings because you are trying to use the $_GET['deck'] variable even if it doesn't exist. Do an isset check on it first before using it

Comment: as @georaldc stated, have you put a if(isset)) on it?
I would add to that to have it do an `else { $deck; }` (just declaring the variable)